# Django ORM - queryset order by filtered foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Question: Can a filtered left join or a join on a subquery (very simple in postgres) be accomplished with the Django ORM/queryset functions?

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class DashboardItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class DashboardItemUserData(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    dashboard_item = models.ForeignKey(DashboardItem)
    is_favorite = BooleanField()
```

The DashboardItemUserData stores per-user information as to whether the user has "favorited" the dashboard item. I need to be able to sort DashboardItem's based on the current requesting user. However, I need the join to be filtered since the ordering should respect the current user regardless of if other users have "favorited" the item or not.

Query I would think would work (or similar):

```
current_user = request.user
DashboardItem.objects.annotate(is_favorite=DashboardItemUserData.objects.filter(user=current_user).values('is_favorite')).order_by('is_favorite','name')
```

Here's what I would do in SQL:

[postgres query using where on join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxUi6.jpg)

[postgres query using subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llu1l.jpg)

Comment: I don't think you need to use a nested select query. Couldn't you INNER JOIN user_item_favorites onto dashboard_items and do the WHERE user = 1 right before the ORDER BY?

Comment: Thanks, good point. I added that into the question and clarified the question relating to how the ORM translates to either of these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own first question...but will leave this here in case anyone else comes across it. I've found two approaches that will work here:

1. If we can guarantee a database record for each user in the DashboardItemUserData table, we can simply use "filter()" to create an inner join. Since a user will have a record for all DashboardItem's, an inner join won't exclude any.

```
current_user = request.user
DashboardItem.objects.filter(dashboarditemuserdata__user=current_user).order_by('is_favorite', 'name')
```

2. If we cannot guarantee a record for each user in DashboardItemUserData, we can use the Django ORM's FilteredRelation feature. This will create a left outer join where we first filter the DashboardItemUserData table to only the user in question (so we get the right user data but don't blow up the left join).

```
current_user = request.user
DashboardItem.objects.annotate(user_item_data=FilteredRelation('dashboarditemuserdata', condition=Q(dashboarditemuserdata__user=current_user))).order_by('user_item_data__is_favorite', 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DashboardItemUserData.objects.filter(user_id=1).\
    annotate(name=dashboard_item__name).\
    order_by('is_favorite', 'name')
```

Subquery would make sense if this was a LEFT join. Or if it contained TOP/LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks. This does work in this simple example, however I'd want to return a queryset of "DashboardItem"s as this table will be more complex and require additional logic around it. Annotating info from this table back to the user specific table unfortunately avoids the bigger problem.